# se insertan los usuarios pero me sale este mensaje "The email address is already in use by another account"

Tags: firebase, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]en vez del mensaje de welcome + user.uid porque pasa esto si ya se insertaron los usuarios?, por favor ayudenme les agradesco a los que se tomen el tiempo y la molestia de decirme donde esta fallando mi codigo, de antemano muchas gracias, hago la descripcion lo mas larga posible porque me dice que mi publicacion es casi puramente codigo.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.

Esta es el componente Auten.js

```js
import React from 'react';

const firebase = require('firebase');

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXX",
    authDomain: "fir-login-2d466.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://fir-login-2d466.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fir-login-2d466",
    storageBucket: "fir-login-2d466.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "303960039772",
    appId: "1:303960039772:web:909c622cd19a61f2"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

class Auten extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            err: ''
        };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
    }

    login(event)
    {
        const email = this.refs.email.value;
        const password = this.refs.password.value;

        console.log(email, password);

        const auth = firebase.auth();

        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        promise.catch(e => {
            let err = e.message;
            console.log(err);
            this.setState({err: err});
        });
    }

    signup()
    {
        const email = this.refs.email.value;
        const password = this.refs.password.value;

        console.log(email, password);

        const auth = firebase.auth();

        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        promise.then(user => {
            let err = "Welcome " + user.email;
            firebase.database().ref('/users' + user.uid).set({
                email: user.email
            });
            console.log(user);
            this.setState({err: err});
        });
        promise.catch(e => {
           let err = e.message;
           console.log(err);
           this.setState(({err: err}));     
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
               <input id = "email" ref = "email" type = "email" placeholder = "Enter your email." /><br />
               <input id = "password" ref = "password" type = "password" placeholder = "Enter your password." /><br />
               <p>{this.state.err}</p>
               <button onClick = {this.login}>Log In</button>
               <button onClick = {this.signup}>Sign Up</button>
               <button>Log Out</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Auten;
```

Aqui hay una imagen mostrando que si se insertan los usuarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ten en cuenta de no publicar tus ApiKeys en las preguntas, pues otros usuarios podrian utilizarla para consumir tu servicio

Comment: no te preocupes es solo un ejercicio de prueba, ahora me sale este error Error: `Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'usersundefined.email'`

Comment: de verdad que solo registre el mail una vez y no me aparecio ningun welcome, tengo los botones de `Log In` y `Sign Up` por separado.

Comment: ¿El error que agregue en las ediciones a que se debe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en que no estas logueando al usuario, sino que lo estas registrando

Con `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)` creas el usuario , con `signInUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)` lo logueas

En la promesa de exito de `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` podes llevarlo a otra pantalla y darle el mensaje de bienvenida, pero eso va a ser la primera vez ya que ese usuario no esta registrado en la base de datos, pero luego, si lo volves a hacer no vas a poder por que ya esta creado ese usuario, y te va a saltar el fallo en la promesa con la leyenda de que ya existe un usuario con ese email en la base de datos

Para solucionarlo vas a tener que usar

```
signInUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
```

Puedes leer un poco mas [AQUÍ](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth?hl=es-419)

Comment: lo hice solo una vez y no me dio el mensaje de welcome

Answer (score 0):

ya pude solucionar el error hay que cambiar ambos metodos por esto:

```js
login(event)
    {
        const email = this.refs.email.value
        const password = this.refs.password.value
        const auth = firebase.auth()
        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    
        promise
        .then(user => {
        console.log(user)
        let lout = document.getElementById('logout')
        let message = `Welcome ${user.user.email}`
        this.setState({err: message})
    
        lout.classList.remove('hide')
        })
        .catch(e => {
        let err = e.message
        console.log(err)
        this.setState({err: err})
        })
    }

    signup()
    {
        const email = this.refs.email.value
        const password = this.refs.password.value
        const auth = firebase.auth()
        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        promise
        .then(user => {
          let err = `Welcome ${user.user.email}`
          console.log(user)
          console.log(user.user.uid)
          firebase.database().ref('users/'+user.user.uid).set({
            email: user.user.email
          })
          console.log(user)
          this.setState({err: err})
        })
        .catch( e => {
          let err = e.message
          console.log(err)
          this.setState({err: err})
        })
    }
```